# How can I implement the form action with React Js?

Tags: reactjs, authorize.net

How can I implement

```
<form method="post" action="https://accept.authorize.net/customer/addPayment">
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="pfGaUNntEKMGfyWPmI4p+Bb4TJf2F0NCoCBp3cOXB7"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Manage my payment and shipping information"/>
</form>
```

in React JS? I have tried to implement it, but it did not redirect it to the form. I am calling the token via an API and also the action link.

Comment: you need to write a `submitHandler function` which will trigger by `onSubmit` event of the form. Inside that handler function you need to send ajax call.

Comment: I am new to that, any idea how I can do that ?

Comment: you can check this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-forms-in-react